# Determining if a driveitem is checked out or a shared lock is on the item

Tags: microsoft-graph

I am using Graph API in C# and version 5.12.
I am trying to get information about if a DriveItem has been checked out OR if a shared lock is active on the DriveItem. A shared lock is active if the item is opened for editing by any user. This can be seen by opening a Word document in SharePoint and then trying to check it out. Then you will see this error:

[image]

I have been searching for a way to check if a file has been checked out or has a share lock but I am unable to find it. Is it possible to check the status of a DriveItem to determine the checkout/locks active on the DriveItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible using the Graph API. It is, however, possible using the SharePoint rest api v1 service and that is how I managed to get this information.

There is a LockedByUser property on File that is is set to the User that opens the file with a shared lock. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541288(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

This is a link that can be used in Postman, for example:

```
https://X.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteTitle}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/{siteTitle}/shared documents/{folderPath}')/Files('{fileNameWithExtension}')/LockedByUser
```

Here is also a link to the Graph community where it is suggested to add this functionality to the Graph API: [LockedByUser in Graph API suggestion on feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/47b4aa45-b37a-ed11-a81b-000d3ae32cd0) I suggest that you upvote it there if you want this feature to be added.